# DROP all table with a specific name prefix

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I have a database which store old installation wordpress tables.
I would like to clean up a bit so I am looking for a query can delete the table based on the prefix table name.

In this case I want to drop all table that start with "_wordpress_1_"

```
   _wordpress_1_eruiweuriw
   _wordpress_2_jshfiojdwi
   _wordpress_1_fksdjfksdj
   _wordpress_1_fskdjfksdf
   _wordpress_3_kfsjdfsdkf
```

So iam trying:

```
 USE database_name;
 SELECT * FROM database_name WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%_wordpress_1_%';
```

I guess i cannot use like in the where statement for table name but just for table column??
Could I get any tips on how to achive this?

Comment: `SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'your_database_name' AND table_name LIKE '%_wordpress_1_%';`?

Comment: `SELECT table_name`  ? -> I want to drop multiple table with same prefix name

Comment: You need stored procedure with dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE drop_all_tables (IN dbase TEXT, IN prefix TEXT)
BEGIN
SELECT CONCAT('DROP TABLE ', GROUP_CONCAT(table_name))
INTO @sql
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_schema = dbase 
  AND table_name LIKE CONCAT(prefix, '%');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DROP PREPARE stmt;
-- and now cry if you make a mistake in parameters
END
```

then

```
CALL drop_all_tables ('wordpress_database', '_wordpress_1_');
```

Comment: Thank you, I will test. The same procedure can be used to copy ALL table with same prefix into another db right?

Comment: @Dho No, you cannot copy multiple tables in one statement. You'll need a cycle over a cursor, and copy table-by-table.

Answer (score 0):

you don't can do it with only one MySQL Command, you can use MySQL to construct the statement for you:

In the MySQL shell or PHPMyAdmin, Paste the following query with changing the prefix :

```
SELECT CONCAT( 'DROP TABLE ', GROUP_CONCAT(table_name) , ';' ) 
AS statement FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_name LIKE '_wordpress_1_%';
```

This will generate a DROP statement which you can than copy and execute to drop the tables.